# NSolve cannot solve system of equations in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following two equations:

```
Ieq1=-1 - (0.763546 I1 (1/(-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2) - (
18 (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2))/(
I1 (-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2)^2)) X^1.3)/((1.36- 
I1) (I1/(-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2))^2.3) + (
0.587343 X^1.3)/((1.36- 
I1) (I1/(-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2))^1.3) + (
0.587343 I1 X^1.3)/((1.36- 
I1)^2 (I1/(-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2))^1.3);

Ieq2=1 + (0.763546 I1^2 ((20 (-8 + 10/I2))/I2^2 - (20 (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2))/
I2^2) (-8 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2) X^1.3)/((1.36- 
I1) (I1/(-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/
  I2)^2))^2.3 (-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2)^3) - (
 0.587343 I1 ((20 (-8 + 10/I2))/I2^2 - (20 (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2))/
I2^2) (-8 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2) X^1.3)/((1.36- 
I1) (I1/(-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/
  I2)^2))^1.3 (-(-8 + 10/I2)^2 + (1 - 9/I1 + 10/I2)^2)^2);
```

and then I use the NSolve function:

```
 NSolve[{Ieq1 == 0, Ieq2 == 0}, {I1, I2}]
```

because I want to solve each one as a function of X. But unfortunately it just gets stuck while running. Do you have any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Comment: Hi bubbly, welcome to Mathematica.SE! NSolve is not suitable for your goal, as it will only provide numerical solutions given sufficient information. If you want to express the results in terms of the unknown X you may want to try Solve.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I doubt Solve would be able to solve such a system.

Comment: Yes, Solve was my first idea but it didn't work..

Comment: @ruslan Not much else to chose from if you want a solution in terms of X as was asked. I note that your solution doesn't do that.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries well you're right, though after computing numerically you can use `Interpolation[]` to "express in terms of `X`" in some sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will not give you the complete solution for your problem (which appears not quite trivial), but rather some startup to get used to a wider range of tools Mathematica gives you. If you don't understand what some function used in my code does, you can always move text cursor to its name and press `F1` in Mathematica notebook interface to see documentation.

First, to ease work with your big functions, let's define them as functions instead of just symbols (this will be necessary for Plot3D, for instance):

```
Clear[Ieq1,Ieq2]
Ieq1[X_,I1_,I2_]=YourFirstFunction;
Ieq2[X_,I1_,I2_]=YourSecondFunction;
```

Now let's see how these two functions look with an example `X=0.2`:

```
With[{X = 0.2},
Plot3D[
{
    Log[Abs[Ieq1[X, I1, I2]]],
    Log[Abs[Ieq2[X, I1, I2]]]
}, {I1, -10, 10}, {I2, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> {-10, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
]
```

[image: result]

We used `Log[Abs[...]]` here to see zeroes of each function. You can see that there's plenty of zeroes for each function.

But, let's see whether your functions have any *simultaneous* roots (I use 500 plot points here to see fine details of the function; if your machine is not too fast this may take several minutes to render and appear sluggish when trying to rotate):

```
With[{X = 0.2}, Plot3D[
{
    Log[Abs[Ieq1[X, I1, I2]] + Abs[Ieq2[X, I1, I2]]]
}, {I1, -10, 10}, {I2, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 2}, 
PlotPoints -> 500, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Exclusions -> None]
]
```

[image]

So, we have a candidate for a root. Let's try it with FindRoot with nearby starting values:

```
res=With[{X = 0.2}, Chop@FindRoot[
{
    Ieq1[X, I1, I2], Ieq2[X, I1, I2]
}, {I1, 0.5}, {I2, 0.5}, MaxIterations -> 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
]
```

> {I1 -> 1., I2 -> 0.354532}

You'll get a `FindRoot::lstol` warning, but you do get some values. Let's check whether they are good enough:

```
Ieq1[0.2, I1, I2] /. res
Ieq2[0.2, I1, I2] /. res
```

> -8.93913*10^-8
>
> -4.26765*10^-7

So, OK, we've found the roots for `X=0.2`. You'll have now to use `Table` to make final list of `{X,{I1,I2}` elements, but:

**NOTE** Using `FindRoot` you **always** have to check if the roots found are indeed the roots, *especially* if you get some warnings. This may make your experience with automatizing your computations with `Table` considerably harder. If you get wrong values, try perturbing starting values. Also, always try to visualize the functions you work with if it's possible (i.e. they have not too many arguments).